# Problems with Unicode strings

Tags: c#, encryption, encoding

I have a textfile with encrypted Text. For example:

휗✹➂鳄ⅅⵘ械뱥間뒝贍ꤦ掁☞ೇ

쎠ԠƳᒸ略ⱉ㾤歓ر㗋鲔\ud953

Now I want to decrypt these one. The code looks like this:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("input.txt");   
List<string> DecList = new List<string>();
foreach(var line in toDecList)
{
    string decrypted = Decrypt(@line);
    DecList.Add(decrypted);             
}

File.WriteAllLines("output.txt", toEncList);
```

For the first example I get no error. For the second I got a Cryptographic Exception. If I copy the text from the file into clipboard and paste it directly into the code I got no error.

So I think there is a problem with the Encoding. I also tried it with

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("input.txt", Encoding.Unicode);
```

But the same problem occurs.

Has someone an idea?

Comment: Are you sure you're finding the right line endings in the encrypted file? An encrypted piece of code might have line endings inside the encrypted string that belong to the encrypted data.

Comment: @RoyiNamir why? I can't read it ; ) But to be serious what exactly exception you get out there?

Comment: Use `File.ReadLines(string path, Encoding encoding)` and pass the encoding the file has.

Comment: As per my thinking you should check when you create encrypted file. At that point proper encoding must choose.

Comment: Each line contain one string to decrypt. And if I debug, the string looks like ok. The exception is Rjndael CryptographicException “Length of the data to encrypt is invalid.”

Answer (score 0):

You need to be very sure to keep text separate from bytes.  Text is always a representation of some readable text in some alphabet or other.  Encrypted text is a stream of bytes.  Mixing the two will cause problems.  For example, UTF-8 text may not contain certain byte combinations, while those bytes may occur in a byte stream.

Your code appears to treat encoded bytes as strings.  This is a fundamental error, and will cause problems.  If you want to store encrypted bytes as text then you need to convert the bytes into a text format, such as Base64, for storage.  You then need to convert the Base64 text back to bytes before decrypting.

Something like:

```
encryptedBytes <- encrypt(plaintext, password)
storableString <- base64(encryptedBytes)
DB.store(storableString)
```

followed by:

```
b64Cyphertext <- DB.retrieve()
cypherbytes <- 46esab(b64Cyphertext)
decryptedText <- decrypt(cypherbytes, password)
```